# OpenAM 11: How to retrieve binary attributes of a user using the OpenAM SOAP web services?

Tags: openam

We're authenticating users against OpenAM using the SOAP web services and a call to IdentityServicesImplService.authenticate(). After that we're calling IdentityServicesImplService.attributes() to get an AttributeResponse from which we read the UserDetails form which we read the user attributes.

A synchronization task goes a different route: We authenticate with an administrative account and read IdentityDetails for users using IdentityServicesImpl.read().

That all works fine until we specify a binary attribute in the LDAP datastore's list of user attributes. OpenAM does not recognize that the attribute is binary (nor do I see a way to specify it) and the SOAP response contains invalid XML.

So the question is: How do we read binary attributes?

Thanks,

Sascha

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no way to retrieve binary attributes using the REST APIs, see [OPENAM-3929](https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-3929).

The ClientSDK should be able to retrieve binary attributes remotely, but even that had a few bugs ([OPENAM-139](https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-139), [OPENAM-2610](https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-2610))

Comment: Thanks. I am wondering. Is the client SDK generally to be preferred over the SOAP web services?

Comment: Pretty much anything is better than SOAP :) The ClientSDK is actually using JAX-RPC endpoints (which isn't much better really), hopefully in the future the REST endpoints will support binary attributes as well.